# Why don't suggested edit reviewers read the question, comments and answers related to the edit?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits, rejection-reasons

I am strongly of the opinion that the majority of edit reviewers do not take the time to go through the question, the comments and answers and *understand* their relevance to the suggested edit *and then* review the edit.

I think the Community bot could do that just as well as those edit reviewers:

```
if (too much red in the original post or too much green in the edited post)
    reject
```

Whereas, ideally, what a human reviewer should do,

```
if (too much red in the original post or too much green in the edited post)
    read the question
    read the comments
    read the answers
    understand all the read material as one coherent post
    if(edit drastically different from understanding)
        reject
```

I have faced this issue too many times (examples of which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1953589) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1922681)). On the other hand, I have been lucky a few times to have my edits reviewed by people who did take the time (one example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1808918)).

I honestly feel really bad for those posters because they definitely need help/want to provide help, but, they do not get enough attention (or get down-voted) because of simple issues like poor grammar, bad formatting, etc. which are fixable by edits and/or clarification by the poster.

Now I understand that there are people who mindlessly edit out stuff/add stuff and that's why this review system is there in the first place. But, I'm sure there are people like me who actually take the time to rephrase the post to more clearly convey their meaning. In my case, I almost always verify my point of view with the poster before editing (the exceptions being when I am 100% sure I've understood it right).

A comment on an [earlier question about a rejected edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176557/why-was-this-edit-rejected-for-changing-the-original-post-too-much) was that the majority of rejected edits actually deserved to be rejected so nothing needs changing. I understand this, but it really does get me down at times.

I've been trying, in vain, to think of some feature request that can at least reduce this occurrence without irritating everyone and worsen the site's user-experience. This is why I'm posting a question to ask the community whether they agree with me (or not) and if some people do, whether they have any ideas. And if they don't, tell me why I'm wrong or the effort isn't worth it :)

Comment: While your linked edit show significant effort on your behalf, they are a bit much. I think I would have rejected them as well. And as for reading the post, comments, answers, etc. the review system in its current presentation is not ideally suited imho.

Comment: @Bart, Do you think it would be feasible to have the editor supply a few relevant links?

Comment: Whether that's feasible or not, I'm not sure it matters all that much. Review, unfortunately, seems to be a job to be rushed through to obtain glorious badges. I can't count the times where I've been carefully reading through material, finally rejecting the suggestion, only to have a message come up saying it has already been accepted. So I'm not sure that will help.

Comment: Okay, one last comment. Looking at your edits, reading through all the content they are ultimately fine edits. However, judging from the review queue alone, you seem to be changing posts into something they were not. Until you get the privilege to edit without review I would try not to do that. And even after that, try to at least have the post resemble what the author originally wrote, only better. After all, it's still their post. And especially when it comes to questions, I can see your edits potentially confuse the original author. Make the post good, but don't rewrite it.

Comment: I understand. In cases like that I try to improve the English, but as minimally as possible. I'm not going to toss out their entire content to transform it into the perfect question. That makes it better but keeps the question closer to what they actually said. And as an added bonus it saves me time.

Comment: @Bart, Good point. Will keep that in mind! Thanks! Could you show me an example of where I possibly confused the author if you can? Just curious

Comment: The [one you link](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1953589) comes close. Don't get me wrong, it's ultimately a good edit. Perhaps, based on the OP's participation in comments he will have no problem with it. But you don't merely seem to correct, but rewrite the question as you would have asked it. Especially if you have an OP with a poor grasp of English and new to a subject, I can imagine them ending up thinking "is that what I'm asking?".

Comment: @Bart, That is very true. I can imagine myself in that position as well. I'll be more careful from now :) Thanks!

Comment: "Now I understand that there are people who mindlessly edit out stuff/add stuff and that's why this review system is there in the first place." There are also people who mindlessly review edits regardless of their nature. This is how such behavior (or unbehavior) comes about.

Comment: @Bolt, Would it be feasible, according to you, to allow the suggester of the edit to supply a few relevant links (if he wants to) to prove his/her edit's correctness?

Comment: I suspect if you need to provide multiple references for an edit, you probably should have written a new answer instead.

Comment: @Wooble, Not necessarily an answer. What if I'm editing a question?

Comment: @Anish Ram: How would that work?

Comment: @Bolt, It would make it easier for the reviewer to assess the edit because he/she is now just a few clicks away from the "comments" referred to by the editor in the edit-comment.

Comment: @AnishRam Ultimately I think the best solution is if you need a major edit to a question, it is best left to the OP or a 2K user.  If you need to reference multiple comments or answers to justify your edit, I think you are changing too much of the post.

Comment: @psubsee2003, But in that time, the post will most likely have gathered quite a few downvotes and I think most people's eyes just skip downvoted posts.

Comment: @AnishRam I understand that part of it, but this is really a no-win situation.  In general we have a larger problem with bad approvals than with bad rejections, so most likely anything that will help reduce the bad rejections may have the unintended side effect of permitting more bad approvals.

Comment: @psubsee2003, Hmmm, that does make sense.

Comment: @AnishRam to BoltClock's point earlier, if you want something to have a better chance of getting approved, trying being less "aggressive" with the changes, maybe cleaning up the English and making some grammar fixes, but not rewriting the whole question.  Your edits are good but when you are going through the review queue and you see a suggestion (like one of your examples) where you changed virtually the entire post, it is hard not to rejected it as a radical edit.  There are so many reviewers and so few suggestions that there is not enough time to review
 as thoroughly as you could.

Comment: @psubsee2003, Yeah. Good point. Less aggressive. Definitely!